# Routing errors in rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I'm currently working on my project but having some challenges. I have a a Project model that has Comment objects nested into it I can create a new comment but when I try to edit the comment associated to the project object i get this weird error in the browser that shows that I'm trying to edit a comment that belongs to a project that doesn't exist. Actually when I check the url the id of the project doesn't really exist. For instance if i want to edit a comment that belongs to a project with an id of 1 the error message indicates that I want to edit a comment that belongs to a project with an id 2. I've tried all I know but can't get to the root of the problem. 
this is how my comment controller looks like

[8:04] 
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_project

```
def index
    @projects = Project.all
    if params[:project_id]
      @comments = @project.comments.all
      redirect_to @comments
    end
  end



 def new
    if params[:project_id]
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @comment = @project.comments.build
    end
  end

 def create
  if params[:project_id]
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

   @comment = @project.comments.create(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @comment
    else
      render "new"
    end
   end
  end

 def show
    if params[:project_id]
    @project = Project.find_by(:id => params[:id])
    @comment = @project.comments.find_by(:id => params[:id])

 end
end

 def edit
    if params[:project_id]
    @comment = @project.comments.find_by(:id => params[:id])
  end
 end

 def update
    if params[:project_id]
    @comment = @project.comments.find_by(:id => params[:id])
    @comment.update(comment_params)
      redirect_to @comment

     render "edit", notice: "You cannot update the comment"
    end
  end

 def destroy
    @comment = @project.comments.find_by(:id => params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Comment has been successfully deleted"
    redirect_to @project
  end

 private

  def find_project
    @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :project_id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your show method you have used params[:id] as the project_id

```
@project = Project.find_by(:id => params[:id])
```

try changing it to

```
 @project = Project.find_by(:id => params[:project_id])
```

Comment: Tyesh, I tried your suggestion but it still didn't work